# Find my iPad/iphone device when device is switched off

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

with MobileMe and Find My iPhone app on appstore I can find my ipad/iphone device if the device is switched on and connected to wifi and in iOS5.1 to iCloud.. however, i just need to be absolutely sure that apple has no method of finding a device if the device is switched off. If anyone knows of any way of doing so, pls help by letting me know..

Thanks in advance for your help on this...

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: No actually, I did search to be sure and did not find anything, but wanted to be doubly sure.. the customer was adamant that we be extremely sure nothing existed, so thought of checking on this forum too.. I needed to be sure that there is no API available (private or otherwise) using which either the device or the program can do anything of this sort

Comment: **Not a programming question**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, well kinda. First of all you have to be jailbroken. Second it is a paid app unlike Find My iPhone. This does not actually allow you to track the device after its been shut down, but it does prevent whoever stole it from shutting it down.

Read More: [here](http://modmyi.com/content/6431-giveaway-we-re-giving-away-200-worth-cylay-licenses-again-celebrating-untether-comments3.html) (Its an old post so don't expect anything from that old Giveaway)

Comment: thank you for this info! I must say, developers are very imaginative :-) It helps to know there is a possible solution. It makes me wonder how this must have been implemented. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. But next time, don't post a non-programming question here. Instead use the [Modmyi](http://modmyi.com/forums/) forums.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is off... then... it's off... off the grid, it doesn't exist anymore to the network.

There is no way.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the case myself right after my iPad was stolen. I was able to track it until the theft turned it off. AFAIK there is no way of locating an off-switched device. (I'd be happy if I were wrong. :)